# How to use a 30" lcd monitor 20 meters away from my computer?

Tags: display, dvi, lcd, cable, extension

Is there a long enough dual DVI cable or a way to do this while using  2560x1600 resolution? I have a spare monitor which I want to use it in my kitchen to watch things or even check out a recipe (less rare).

Comment: You might want to explore some form of wifi dongle, such as the devices that let you transmit from your computer to a TV.

Comment: TVs don't do  2560x1600 which she wants.

Comment: Actually I will use raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: The [DVI spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) doesn't specifically state a max length for a single cable, but it does suggest that 4.6m (15 ft) is generally the longest you'll get that will still support resolutions up to 1920x1200 pixels.

If you want longer than that you'll need to look into a DVI Booster, which by the looks of the first Google hit I found can reach up to 50m.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just don't know all these other things like repeater which won't help I guess but what about extender? I saw one that claims to extend up to 150m.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Tripp-Lite-Equalizer-2560x1600-B120-000/dp/B000N5WNJI/ref=pd_sim_e_2?ie=UTF8&refRID=0WYZKRG7YZBTSGJ45Z5H

Comment: That extender would most likely do. It really depends on the resolution you want to work with on the monitor. As you have a 30" I assume it's going to be 1920x1080 at least, and you'll need a booster for that. If you don't care about resolution, then you may find a long enough cable that will kinda work.

Comment: Thanks, no my resolution is 2560x1600 which is what I wanna have. But that extender in amazon claims to support it so I assume that and a long dvi cable should be fine, right? No need for booster?

Answer (score 1):

I see you just selected an answer...

However, if you are going to spend that much money on a DVI Booster, why not just buy a laptop or tablet?  You can hook the laptop to the monitor and have much more control.  In a addition to that, the laptop or tablet is portable.

Comment: @JoanVenge you can pay less.  low end laptops are really cheap.  same for tablets.  why buy something that can only do one thing, when you can spend the same money and get something that does infinitely more?

Comment: You can easily buy a whole computer for $200.  It'll be a low end computer, but you're probably not playing games via that screen anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [https://www.google.com/search?q=DVI+20m+cable](https://www.google.com/search?q=DVI%2020m%20cable) shows a web search found [this extender kit](http://www.networktechinc.com/dvi-dual-link-extend.html) using a multimode fiber optic cable (thinner than a Cat5/6 cable), and [many more DVI splitter cables](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=DVI%20dual%20head%20splitter) were found.